# How to call https web service in Android

Tags: android, web-services, ssl

Hello I am working on android application where I need to call Web Service where I am using `https` protocol. I am able to call simple `http` protocol based web service but did not find any correct solution to call `https`. I found many threads of stackoverflow like [How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0) but all they are bypassing the SSL that results no mean of `https`. I don't want to bypass SSL.

I am doing this but it is not working.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Prepare a request object
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

// Execute the request
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    // Examine the response status
    Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

    // Get hold of the response entity
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
    // to worry about connection release

    if (entity != null) {

        // A Simple JSON Response Read
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
        // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
        instream.close();
    }


} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you have to do is use an https url.  Unless you have some weird self signed cert it should work.  If you do, then you have to add your cert to the device.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23782538/1405983 Hope it will helps you.

Comment: @Prince I think that also bypass the ssl error..

Comment: @GabeSechan yes I want to see how to generate and add cert to the device ? can you explain it how this process goes ?

Comment: @Prince I am not looking to bypass the SSL. I want a correct solution to call https web service

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is complete solution for that. I have written this for my application.

```
/**
 * This Activity is being used to show an alert about certificate exception
 * while communicating to server. User can take action on the alert and
 * {@link X509Certificate} will be added to trust zone if user proceed.
 */
public class SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    /** Key to send certificate via Intent between activities */
    private static final String CERTIFICATE_INTENT_EXTRA = "ssl_certificate";
    /** Key to send failing url via Intent between activities */
    private static final String FAILING_URL_INTENT_EXTRA = "failing_url";
    /** Request code for install certificate */
    private static final int INSTALL_CERTIFICATE = 100;
    private AlertDialog mCertificateDialog;
    /**
     * Certificate which needs to added to trust zone.
     */
    private X509Certificate mX509Certificate;
    /**
     * Url which is being failed for the SSL handshake
     */
    private String mFailingUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // This is UI less Activity. Layout should not be set.
        // Read certificate intent and install
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can not show dialog, intent is null");
            finish();
            return;
        }
        this.mX509Certificate = (X509Certificate) intent
                .getSerializableExtra(CERTIFICATE_INTENT_EXTRA);
        this.mFailingUrl = (String) intent.getStringExtra(FAILING_URL_INTENT_EXTRA);
        if ((this.mX509Certificate == null) || (this.mFailingUrl == null)) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Can not show dialog, certificate or failingurl is null");
            finish();
            return;
        }
        // Inform user for certificate error
        if ((mCertificateDialog == null)
                || (mCertificateDialog.isShowing() == false)) {
            // Show dialog only when if it it not showing.
            // Certificate will be updated, and will be read
            // from dialog when click on ok. So no need to
            // dismiss current dialog.
            showSSLCertificateAcceptDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Prevent back press
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if ((mCertificateDialog != null)
                && (mCertificateDialog.isShowing() == true)) {
            mCertificateDialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Shows an alert dialog about SSL certificate issue. If user proceed,
     * certificate will be added to trust zone, and this dialog will not be
     * shown for same certificate.
     */
    private void showSSLCertificateAcceptDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity.this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.abouthp_icon);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.untrusted_cert_dialog_title);
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.untrusted_cert_dialog_action_ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        installCertificate();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.untrusted_cert_dialog_action_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        // TODO Retry the failing url
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        mCertificateDialog = builder.create();
        mCertificateDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mCertificateDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Install {@link X509Certificate} to trust zone. First this method will try
     * to add certificate from background and on fail it will show a dialog to
     * add certificate. This method must be called from an Activity, as it need
     * an activity instance.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void installCertificate() {
        X509Certificate certificate = SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity.this.mX509Certificate;
        if (certificate != null) {
            byte[] encodedCert = null;
            try {
                encodedCert = certificate.getEncoded();
            } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (encodedCert != null) {
                installUsingIntent(encodedCert, INSTALL_CERTIFICATE);
            }
        } else {
            // TODO Retry the failing url
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Install certificate to trust zone using intent. User action will be
     * required while installing.
     * 
     * @param encodedCert
     *            of {@link X509Certificate}
     * @param requestCode
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void installUsingIntent(byte[] encodedCert, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
        // Default Alias name. User can change it.
        intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, "MY Certificate");
        intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, encodedCert);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case INSTALL_CERTIFICATE:
            // No matter if action was success or not, retry to connect with
            // failed url and finish this activity.
            // You can retry the failiing url
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show {@link SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity} to inform user that, while
     * communicating to server there is untrusted certificate exception. User
     * can take action, certificate will be added to trust zone if user proceed.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param certificate
     *            {@link X509Certificate} to be added to trust zone.
     * @param failingUrl
     *            is an url for SSL certificate error occurred, purpose of this
     *            url is to retry the same url after user action either
     *            cancelled or proceed.
     */
    public static void show(Context context, X509Certificate certificate,
            String failingUrl) {
        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(appContext,
                SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        intent.putExtra(CERTIFICATE_INTENT_EXTRA, certificate);
        intent.putExtra(FAILING_URL_INTENT_EXTRA, failingUrl);
        appContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And here is the utility class which help you to handle SSL certificate error and install to device

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * This class will perform all network related calls like post, get and put.
 */
public class NetworkUtility {
    protected static final String TAG = NetworkUtility.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Connection timeout. 15 seconds
     */
    private static final int HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 150000;

    /**
     * Returns Default HTTP client with socket factories initialised.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param targetUrl
     *            to do request
     * @return Default HTTP Client
     */
    private static HttpClient getDefaultHttpClient(Context context,
            String targetUrl) {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,
                HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        try {
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(
                    context.getApplicationContext(), targetUrl), 443));
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        }
    }

    /**
     * TrustManager to accept all certificates. It does not do any certificates
     * validation.
     * 
     * TODO: Once we have actual certificates this implementation should be
     * changed accordingly.
     */
    private static class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        private X509TrustManager mOriginalX509TrustManager;
        private Context mContext;
        private String mTargetUrl;

        /**
         * @param context
         *            - application context.
         * @param targetUrl
         *            - to do request.
         */
        public MyTrustManager(Context context, String targetUrl) {
            try {
                this.mContext = context;
                this.mTargetUrl = targetUrl;
                TrustManagerFactory originalTrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                        .getInstance("X509");
                originalTrustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
                TrustManager[] originalTrustManagers = originalTrustManagerFactory
                        .getTrustManagers();
                this.mOriginalX509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) originalTrustManagers[0];
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            try {
                // Verify if the certificate has been trusted.
                // This validation will pass if certificate has
                // been added by user or system.
                mOriginalX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(cert, authType);
            } catch (CertificateException originalException) {
                // Certificate has not present into trust zone.
                // Find first certificate from the array of certificates which
                // needs to install.
                X509Certificate certificate = getCertificateToInstall(cert);
                Log.d(TAG, "Showing dialog for certificate exception...");
                // Show dialog where user can install this certificate
                SSLCertificateErrorDialogActivity.show(this.mContext,
                        certificate, this.mTargetUrl);
                throw originalException;
            }
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get certificate to be installed from the given list of certificates. It
     * iterates all certificates from CA and if a certificate, from the given
     * array is not present into CA, this method returns that certificate.
     * 
     * @param certificates
     * @return {@link X509Certificate} to install.
     */
    private static X509Certificate getCertificateToInstall(
            X509Certificate[] certificates) {
        X509Certificate result = null;
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
            if (ks != null) {
                ks.load(null, null);
                boolean certFound = false;
                for (X509Certificate certificate : certificates) {
                    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
                    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
                        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks
                                .getCertificate(alias);
                        if (certificate.equals(cert) == true) {
                            certFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (certFound == false) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Not found certificate");
                        // Need to install this certificate
                        result = certificate;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


    private static class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        private javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory mFactory;

        public MySSLSocketFactory(Context context, String targetUrl)
                throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super((KeyStore) null);
            try {
                SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslcontext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new MyTrustManager(
                        context, targetUrl) }, null);
                mFactory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
                setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return mFactory.createSocket();
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String s, int i, boolean flag)
                throws IOException {
            return mFactory.createSocket(socket, s, i, flag);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Use is very simple as below

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpClient = getDefaultHttpClient(context, url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: Afaik I need to put the keystore file in raw folder but I did not find such in your answer.

Comment: Where did you added that into question???  This will add certificate into device trust zone.

Comment: oh sorry can you please tell me what is device trust zone ?

Comment: Android gives a store where you can store your certificates (i.e. user certificates) from ICS. This is known as trust zone. You can see your certificates at `Setting -> Security -> Trusted credentials -> USER`. Into `SYSTEM` tab you see preloaded certificates.

Comment: wow I didn't know about this but how to store your certificates there in trust zone ?

Comment: @Williams I am sure you didn't tried the code I have given. `installUsingIntent()` does install the certificate.

Comment: I have not tried your code yet but it is really awesome. +1

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar I'm using HttpsTransportSE from Ksoap2 to call a secured web service. could you please explain how I can use your classes to register the target url in trust zone when HttpsTransportSE  give me "invalid cert authority error".

Comment: I'm not able to do these. can you be at any help ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ What is the issue?

Comment: I have copied each and everything form your answer, Do I require certificate/keystore ? because I'm getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)`

Comment: This seems other issue, look like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741405/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-connection-reset-by-peer-while

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
 SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

// set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                    return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
            }
} }, new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

// apache HttpClient version >4.2 should use BasicClientConnectionManager
ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
```

Comment: I found many threads of stackoverflow like How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0 but all they are bypassing the SSL that results no mean of https. I don't want to bypass SSL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android?lq=1 try this @Williams