# Add ssl certificate to android app

Tags: android

Good day, everyone.

I need to add ssl certificate to my application.
I try to find solution, but couldn't find one works.
For example, blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html
i have *.crt file, not *.pem

Comment: Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624439/how-to-call-https-web-service-in-android/24624697#24624697. I have added similer solution.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15901653/1785412