# Https url is not working but http url is working fine in android

Tags: android, url, web

Please guide me to find the problem in this code, when i use url with HTTP then it works fine but with HTTPS it's giving problem.I have googled but couldn't find a solution. It would be appreciable if someone guide me to save my time Thanks

```
public String doRequest() {

    String serverUrl = Constants.BASE_URL + mAction;
    Log.d("usm_serverUrl",serverUrl);
    if (mParams != null) {
        serverUrl += "?" + mParams;
    }
    Log.d("usm_serverUrl",serverUrl);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            // Do normal input or output stream reading
            Log.d("usm_requestCode","Successful");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("usm_requestCode","Failed");
           // response = "FAILED"; // See documentation for more info on response handling
        }
        //HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        Log.d("debug", "get-url: " + serverUrl);
        String response = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        Log.d("debug", "get-url: " + serverUrl + "\n post-response: " + response);
        return response;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
11-30 22:43:30.553    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
11-30 22:43:30.554    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
11-30 22:43:30.555    5031-5398/com.dhcollator.routetoschool W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624439/how-to-call-https-web-service-in-android

Comment: Did you get the solution? me too facing the same problem

Comment: @KartikShah in my case issue was with ssl certificate from server side, but answer of Deepak Goyal may help you in this post.

Comment: Can you describe the issue, I too am using SSL pinning for my application

Answer (score 1):

For https url connection to work in android, use HttpsUrlConnection instead of HttpUrlConnection.
See [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) here

Comment: Thanks but 'm still getting the problem . The problem is with the ssl certificate, can you please guide that from where to get the file for the following code that need to replaced with "load-der.crt"

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));

Comment: can you share your server url.

Answer (score 0):

refer link, it will help as HttpsUrlConnection is required instead of HttpUrlConnection.
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

http://www.java-samples.com/java/POST-toHTTPS-url-free-java-sample-program.htm