# Possible issues when switching from http to https in Android

Tags: android, http, https, ssl-certificate

I'm working on and Android application which currently works using http connection. Now it is going to be changed to https. I want to know whether there will occur any issue in my Android app if I do so.Will it work the same way before? I'm new to this scenario. So I don't know much about this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624439/how-to-call-https-web-service-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate authority that signed the certificate of your server is well known, then there is nothing to worry about. The framework handles it. However, if your server's certificate is signed by an unknown CA, then you need some extra work. Check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) for further details.